# Rails 5 strong parameters with nested multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I am trying to save an object which has a recipe and multiple ingredients inside it. The data comes from my angular 2 app which passes the object as JSON. My rails 5 api application will receive the recipe object and save it directly to my DB using the strong parameters. Right now I can save the recipe object to the database but for some reason the ingredients inside it isn't being saved. I have checked the rails documentation and I found no problem with my current code. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :ingredients
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end
```

ingredient.rb

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :recipe
end
```

recipe_controller.rb

```
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
  if @recipe.save                                                                                                                                                 
    render json: @recipe, status: :created, location: @recipe
  else
    render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:name , :description, :imagePath, ingredients_attributes: [ :id, :name, :amount])
end
```

my console log

```
      Started POST "/recipes" for ::1 at 2017-01-09 11:40:44 +0900
      ActiveRecord::SchemaMigrationLoad(0.3ms)SELECT`schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`

      Processing by RecipesController#create as HTML Parameters: {"name"=>"Spaghetti", "imagePath"=>"http://cdn2.tmbi.com/TOH/Images/Photos/37/300x300/exps36749_SD143203D10__25_1b.jpg", "description"=>"Delicious spaghetti", "ingredients"=>[{"name"=>"Tomato", "amount"=>1}, {"name"=>"Pasta", "amount"=>1}], "recipe"=>{"name"=>"Spaghetti", "description"=>"Delicious spaghetti", "imagePath"=>"http://cdn2.tmbi.com/TOH/Images/Photos/37/300x300/exps36749_SD143203D10__25_1b.jpg"}}


     (0.1ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `recipes` (`name`, `description`, `imagePath`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Spaghetti', 'Delicious spaghetti', 'http://cdn2.tmbi.com/TOH/Images/Photos/37/300x300/exps36749_SD143203D10__25_1b.jpg', '2017-01-09 02:40:44', '2017-01-09 02:40:44')
     (0.7ms)  COMMIT
     Completed 201 Created in 9ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

Comment: Isn't it about strong params? Here is good post [how to permit array in strong params](http://jaketrent.com/post/permit-array-rails-strong-parameters/)

Comment: I tried already ,it just ignores the ingredients inside the recipe object.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5, whenever we define a belongs_to association, it is required to have the associated record present by default after this https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937[change](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937).
If you display the @recipe.errors.messages, you will find

```
{:"ingredient.recipe"=>["must exist"]}
```

Just add 'optional:true' to your belong_to line in the ingredient model.

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :recipe, optional: true
end
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you meant by that. I am trying to save the recipe and the ingredient inside it in my recipe controller.

Comment: It won't save if you have a validation error. The fact that Rails 5 requires the parent association to exists before you can save the record will generate the validation error and won't allow your controller to work. If you try your code in Rails 4, it will work, but not Rails 5. By using optional:true, you allow the child to be saved without having a parent id set yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your console log shows that the params include the key `ingredients`. For nested attributes, you have to use `ingredients_attributes` instead. So make sure your params look like this:

```
{
  "name" => "Spaghetti", 
  "description" => "Delicious spaghetti", 
  "ingredient_attributes" => [
    {"name" => "Tomato", "amount" => 1}, 
    {"name" => "Pasta", "amount" => 1}
  ]
}
```

Why can't we simply use `ingredients` here? Well, this would result in the following code being executed internally:

```
recipe.ingredients = [{"name" => "Tomato", … }]
```

But `recipe.ingredients=` is the attribute writer of the relation, and it only accepts an array of `Ingredient` instances. So you’d have to use it like this:

```
recipe.ingredients = [Ingredient.new("name" => "tomato", …)]
```

Under the hood, using `recipe.ingredients_attributes=` essentially does this conversion from plain hashes into instances of `Ingredient`.